# Is there a name for this property of a topology?

Tags: gn.general-topology, terminology

This property seems like it should have a nice name, but I can't find one anywhere. Does anyone know a name for this?

> For each non-empty open set $U$, there exist proper open subsets $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ such that $U=\cup_i U_i$.

I suppose this could also be formulated as each nonempty open set having an open cover of proper subsets, or being the colimit of its open subsets.

(Also, apologies if this is something obvious I should have thought of.)

Comment: Each *nonempty* open set?

Comment: Absolutely. Will edit to clarify.

Comment: For what it's worth, there's no need to add "nonempty".  The property always holds when U is the empty set, since you can take I to be empty.  

Comment: As stated its just not a good question.  If the space is perfect,
that is every point is a limit point, and points are closed, then a space will have this property.  Its not a research level question.

Comment: @ Ketil Tveiten, re: Charlie Frohman's comment. For what it's worth, I think this is a fine question. I don't think the answer would be obvious to every "research-level" mathematician, although I'm only a first-year graduate student myself...

Comment: @Charlie: Are you saying that serious researchers only study T1 spaces?!?

Comment: I agree with Charlie, and here's why: I don't see off hand any good reason for _caring_ what the name of such a space is.  I mean, if you have examples of some of these spaces, and some result that says that this precise property is what you need for some application, then by all means, it should have a name, and knowing the conventional name will help you look up the appropriate literature.  But as it is, I'd like some motivation before I'll like the question.

Comment: @Charlie Frohman: could you explain your reason for disliking this question? It's a question about the correct name for a property, and you go and say it's not a research level question, which to me sounds true, but irrelevant and silly to mention (when would asking for the name of something be "research level"?).

Also, you give an example class of spaces that have the property. While that is nice and may be helpful to people who didn't think of those examples, and maybe even should have been included by the OP in his question for motivation, I again fail to see how it explains your position.

Answer (score 11):

In spaces where singleton points are closed, your property is equivalent to saying that the space has no isolated points. Or in other words, that it is [perfect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_space).

Clearly, no space with an isolated point can have your property. Conversely, when singletons are closed, then you can subtract one point from any open set and thereby have a proper open subset. So if U has at least 2 points x,y, then U = U-{x} union U-{y}, giving an instance with I of size 2.

However, your property does not imply that points are closed, since the space on reals R, where open sets have the form (-infty, a), has your property, but points are not closed in this space.

Comment: Note that in the example space I give, no finite I would suffice, in contrast to the T1 perfect space situation, where I of size 2 suffices.

Comment: Sort of going the other way (you gave a condition that implies the OP's condition), the condition implies that any local system, ordered by set inclusion, cannot have a smallest element. I think this is saying that local base cannot be finite? (This distinguishes your two examples of R with (-infty,a) and Z with (-infty,n). )

Comment: Willie, this is ,clearly, saying that every local base can not be finite.

Comment: Thanks for verifying my question (I am a bit rusty here).

Answer (score 2):

Are you just saying that the topology is an *atomless* lattice? I'd call it "a space with atomless topology".

Comment: Consider the integers Z, with open sets (-infty,n). This is a topology and is an atomless lattice, but it doesn't have the desired property.

Comment: Hmm, good point. I would like to hear where these spaces come from.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't this just the Base of the topology?

Comment: Huh? Take the set {0,1} with the discrete topology. The subsets { {0}. {1}} form a base of the topology, and they don't satisfy the conditions given in the question. Perhaps you are thinking of something else?

Comment: Stupid me. I missed the word 'Proper'.